# Understanding Render Blocking CSS

Tags: html, css, web-performance

I am trying to understand how CSS is evaluated in a specific setting:

Lets assume I have the following content in my `<head>` tag:

```
<html><head>
...
    <link href="reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="autocomplete.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
... html ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Now, let's assume `reset.css` and `style.css` contain some rules that immediately affect the above the fold content or the the elements in the HTML. However, `autocomplete.css` only contains class used that are used later by some JavaScript.

Now, let's further assume the browser already downloaded `reset.css` and `style.css` but `autocomplete.css` is still pending.
I am wondering what would happen if the browser would do it encounters the blocking script tag at the end of the page? Obviously, it can render the HTML up to the script tag, but is the execution of the script blocked by the missing `autocomplete.css`?

Note that the script tag is not a sync.

I've read: 
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/analyzing-crp

And there it says that the execution of the JavaScript is blocked until the CSSOM is there.

Now:
 1. Will the page start rendering even `autocomplete.css` has not yet arrived? and, 
 2. Is the execution of the `script.js` javascript blocked until the `autocomplete.css` is there?

Note, I am referring to two different things: rendering and script execution.

Comment: Read this. Just a Tip **[Eliminate render blocking css](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/render-blocking-css.html)**

Comment: If `autocomplete.css` is missing then the page will throw a silent error: **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**. But everything will continue to load including your script. If the file exists and it is taking time to load then your page will not load since your css is in the head and it must be loaded before loading the rest of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `CSS` is render blocking. The only exception from this rule would be `CSS` that your `DOM` does not yet know about (loaded async,  built/loaded on the fly via `javascript`).

Until your browser didn't resolve (or thinks it resolved) all `CSS` by building the CSS Object Model, the page won't render and `javascript` will not be executed. However, `resolve` does not necessarily mean `load`. It can mean two things:

- **load & parse**. If it's above 2k lines of code, you're going to notice it when measuring with proper tools. If it's above 10k lines of code, you'll be able to notice it without using any tools. This is regardless if it contains rules concerning elements above the fold or not.
- **not being able to load/parse** (due to network problems or invalid rules) - if an error is returned when `CSS` is loaded/parsed, it will resolve faster and the resulting differences will be hardly noticeable. If the server does not return an error (and just doesn't respond) - that's going to block your CSSOM from building, your page from loading and your scripts from executing.

Resources:

- W3C's [CSSOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/) spec.
- MDN's [CSSOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model) resource page
- [`What is CSSOM?`](https://varvy.com/performance/cssom.html)

Comment: Ok so to be clear: 
The execution of `/js/script.js` will be blocked but the rendering will not?

Comment: That gets to the core of my question: Reading https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/analyzing-crp it sais the execution of the js is blocked until the cssom is constructed (note the script is not async). So will the script be blocked even thoug `autocomplete.css` does not contain rules that apply to the contents of the html? I understand now that  that rendering can happen even though some css are not there?

Comment: @worega I've updated my answer in light of what I could find on the subject. It looks like `javascript` execution is delayed until `CSSOM` is built.

Answer (score 2):

The latest performance recommendations are as follows:

1) Inline all css into the header that the browser needs to render above-the-fold-content. Content which is visible without scrolling.

2) Add all other css to the bottom of the page or better load it asynchronously with something like this: https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS

Answer (score 1):

autocomplete is a css file. As such, it only adds style properties to the classes which are defined in the html. The javascript will still execute correctly, even if the css is missing.

The only thing that might happen is that if the js changes some css styles of the classes which style is defined in autocomplete.css. However even then it's unlikely.

Comment: Don't the browser need to wait with the execution of `/js/script.js` until autocomplete.css has arrived?